# Get version number of AUR package installed

Tags: package-management, aur

I imagine there's some sort of generic command for getting the version number of a specific AUR package I have installed... ideally something I can grep for the specific name, perhaps offering the latest available release number as well? I see similar answers for Ubuntu's dpkg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the version number of *any* installed package by passing pacman the `-Q` (query) flag.

```
pacman -Q $package
```

Pacman considers packages not in the sync database to be foreign: to print a list of all of these packages, you can pass the `-m` option to pacman:

```
pacman -Qm
```

From the `man pacman` page:

> -m, --foreign
>              Restrict or filter output to packages that were not found in the sync database(s). Typically these are packages that were
>   downloaded manually
>              and installed with --upgrade.

As pacman knows nothing of the AUR (other than the fact that these packages, like any installed manually exist outside the repositories), you would need to use an [AUR helper](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AUR_helper) to retrieve the current version of a package in the AUR.

[Cower](https://github.com/falconindy/cower) is generally regarded as one of the better helpers (see the [comparison table](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AUR_helpers#Comparison_table) on the wiki page and **avoid** helpers that feature red fields):

```
cower -s $package
```

Comment: Thanks—didn't expect pacman to handle the AUR stuff as well. Around the same time I found `pacman -Qs $package` (searches for partial hits), which worked a little better as I didn't know the official name of the package